# How can I create a submit button with parameter in the play framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm a bit confused how I can create a submit button with parameter in play framework 2. 
I try this:

```
<form method="GET">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <tr>
            <th>@Messages("id")</th>
            <th>@Messages("errorCode")</th>
            <th>@Messages("errorMessage")</th>
        </tr>
        @for(telegram <- telegrams) {
        <tr>
          <td>@telegram.id</td>
          <td>@telegram.errorCode</td>
          <td>@telegram.errorMessage</td>
          <td><button type="submit" name="action" value="@controllers.routes.Telegrams.createTelegram(telegram.id)">Create Telegram</button></td>
        </tr>
        }
    </table>
</form>
```

In the routes file I add this line:

```
GET     /telegrams/createTelegram/:id  controllers.Telegrams.createTelegram(id: Long)
```

Nothing happens. No error. No controller call.

I don't know what's wrong.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL should go to the `action` attribute of the `form` element (separate `form` for each loop iteration):

```
@for(telegram <- telegrams) {
    <form method="GET" action="@controllers.routes.Telegrams.createTelegram(telegram.id)">
        <tr>
            <td>@telegram.id</td>
            <td>@telegram.errorCode</td>
            <td>@telegram.errorMessage</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Create telegram" /></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
}
```

Comment: But when the URL go to the action attribute of the form element, need I for all rows of the table a separate form?

Answer (score 1):

Why does it have to be a form with a button for a simple `HTTP GET`? A link will do the same job:

```
@for(telegram <- telegrams) {
    <tr>
        <td>@telegram.id</td>
        <td>@telegram.errorCode</td>
        <td>@telegram.errorMessage</td>
        <td><a href="@controllers.routes.Telegrams.createTelegram(telegram.id)">Create telegram</a></td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Sure, a link is also possible, but my end user looks for a button. He is my client, also he gets a button.

Comment: Ok, I see. Maybe he would also accept an image of a button or a small telegram? Many clients are often speaking not literally but figuratively. A button may be here a synonym for everything that performs an action, like sending a telegram.